# how to call webservice from playframework 1.1

Tags: web-services, playframework

I have a webservice with one function checkOrder(String, String, String) return String.

How do I call a function checkOrder from Controller.

My code:

```
WSRequest ws = WS.url("https://www.nganluong.vn/public_api.php?wsdl/");
ws.parameters.put("merchant_id", merchant_site_code);
ws.parameters.put("param", payment_id);
ws.parameters.put("checksum", checksum);
WS.HttpResponse rs = ws.post();
```

Comment: Have a look at this [doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0-M1/JavaWS)

Comment: thanks you, but i use playframework version 1.1

Comment: What is the problem?